# What is the purpose of statement with only numbers?

Tags: c

I came across following code at https://github.com/vamanea/mtd-utils/blob/master/include/common.h#L79:

```
/* Error messages */
#define errmsg(fmt, ...)  ({           \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: error!: " fmt "\n", PROGRAM_NAME, #__VA_ARGS__); \
    -1;                                \
})
```

I couldn't able to understand the purpose of **'-1'** in the above code snippet?

Can anyone throw some light on it pls?

Comment: It is a GNU extension, which basically "returns"  `-1`, (makes errmsg act like a function)

Comment: Thank you Erik W. You are correct. But I couldn't able to get any documentation related to it. I did google with GNU extension as you mention. I still wondering how without using 'return' statement it returns the value.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs